# Gmail warning: the domain not encrypted this message

Tags: email, gmail, tls1.2, smtp-auth, gmail-pop

When I send messages from my server using SMTP Gmail always gets a message with little red lock (left near the senders email) with a message "The domain not encrypted this message".

I send emails via Outlook 2016, using SMTP authentication. pop using SSl 995, smtp using TLS 587. Everything works fine, i can send and receive messages, but Gmail warns that server still not encrypts messages, but the messages are encrypted via TLS.
What can be wrong ?